# Convert binomial tree to paths

Tags: python, numpy

I have a binomial tree stored as an upper triangular matrix:

```
array([[400., 500., 625.],
       [  0., 320., 400.],
       [  0.,   0., 256.]])
```

and I am trying to convert it to a matrix with all possible paths, like:

```
array([[400., 500., 625.],
       [400., 500., 400.],
       [400., 320., 400.],
       [400., 320., 256.]])
```

I've written a snippet that does the job when there are only 2 steps:

```
def unstack_tree(tree):
    output_map = []
    for i in range(tree.shape[0] - 1):
        for j in range(tree.shape[1] - 1):
            output_map.append([tree[0,0], tree[i, 1], tree[i+j, 2]])
    return np.array(output_map)
```

But I am struggling with how to generilize it to N steps to handle, say 3 step tree:

```
array([[400.  , 500.  , 625.  , 781.25],
       [  0.  , 320.  , 400.  , 500.  ],
       [  0.  ,   0.  , 256.  , 320.  ],
       [  0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  , 204.8 ]])
```

I think I need more loops but cannot formulate it

Comment: By 3 steps, do you mean `[tree[0,0], tree[i, 1], tree[i+j, 2], tree[i+j, 3]]` or input matrix of shape `(3+1, 3+1)` ? In other words, what would be the shape of the output for the final 4x4 matrix?

Comment: The shape of the output is a function of total possible outcomes, which is 2^T, so in case when T=3(i.e. input is 4x4), the output is 9x9

Comment: So, for T=2, it should be 4x4? But it is 4x3 in your sample.

Comment: sorry, the dimensions should be (2^T, T+1), so for T=3 it would be (9,4)

Comment: So, it seems it must be `[tree[0,0], tree[i, 1], tree[i+j, 2], tree[i+j, 3]]` for the given 4x4 matrix? Just to confirm, can you add the expected output for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each path can be represented by binary code: first (0, 0), second (0, 1), third
(1, 0) ... . But actual index of array will be represented by cumsum of binary
representation.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

n = 2
b = np.array([[400., 500., 625.],
       [  0., 320., 400.],
       [  0.,   0., 256.]])
a = np.array(list(product((0, 1), repeat=n)))
a = np.c_[[0] * 2 ** n, a]
print(a)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [0 0 1]
#  [0 1 0]
#  [0 1 1]]
a = a.cumsum(axis=1)
print(a)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [0 0 1]
#  [0 1 1]
#  [0 1 2]]
print(np.choose(a, b))
# [[400. 500. 625.]
#  [400. 500. 400.]
#  [400. 320. 400.]
#  [400. 320. 256.]]
```